# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException, but my methods match

Tags: php, laravel

I have a registration form that I'm creating using the blade templating like so:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'registerUser', 'method'=>'POST', 'class'=>'loginForm SignUp')) }}
```

In routes.php, I have the following route:

```
Route::post('registerUser', 'UsersController@doRegister');
```

But when I submit the form, I get a MethodNotAllowedHttpException. Pretty much every other question I've found online about this was a case of the form having the GET method while the route had POST, but mine match, so I'm pretty confused.

Edit: Here's my full routes file:

```
Route::get('', 'UsersController@showLogin');
Route::get('login', 'UsersController@showLogin');
Route::post('doLogin', 'UsersController@doLogin');

Route::get('signUp', 'UsersController@showSignUp');
Route::post('authenticateCode', 'UsersController@authenticateCode');
Route::post('requestCode', 'UsersController@requestCode');

Route::get('showRegister', 'UsersController@showRegister');
Route::post('registerUser', 'UsersController@doRegister');

Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@showDashboard');
```

Here's the controller function:

```
public function doRegister() {
    $rules = array(
        'fname'                 => 'required|alpha|min:2',
        'lname'                 => 'required|alpha|min:2',
        'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'phone'                 => 'required|alpha_num|min:7',
        'company'               => 'required|alpha_spaces|min:2',
        'password'              => 'required|alpha_num|between:6,12|confirmed', // these password rules need to be improved
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|alpha_num|between:6,12'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validator->passes()) {
        $user = User::create(array(
            'fname'      => Input::get('fname'),
            'lname'      => Input::get('lname'),
            'email'      => Input::get('email'),
            'password'   => Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
            'phone'      => Input::get('phone'),
            'company'    => Input::get('company')
        ));

        // Update the invite key that was passed to the register page
        // with this new user's ID.
        $key = InviteKey::find(Input::get('key'));
        $key->user_id = $user->id;
        $key->save();

        return Redirect::to('login')->with('message', 'Thank you for registering!');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('register')
            ->with('message', 'The following errors occurred')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    }
}
```

Comment: post all your routes file please

Comment: @TheShiftExchange updated my original post with my full routes file.

Comment: shouldnt `register` be `get` - and meanwhile `registerUser` is `post`? Your routes look wrong to me...

Comment: Post your controller function 'doRegister'

Comment: Why don't you use `action` instead of `url` in your `Form::open()`? This way you are always sure that the url is correct.

Comment: Hello you have written that: In routes.php, I have the following route:
`Route::post('register', 'UsersController@doRegister');` after that you have written:  Edit: Here's my full routes file:   `Route::post('register', 'UsersController@showRegister');`   so which case is right ?

Comment: the content before the edit and after the edit doesn't match.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange, sorry I got mixed up while editing the file. The first "register" route is:
    Route::post('showRegister', 'UsersController@showRegister');

Comment: @TheShiftExchange, I've also changed the 'showRegister' route to a GET rather than a POST, but this hasn't affected my original problem at all.

Comment: Can you post your controller?

Comment: @Joey, I added the controller function in the main post.